# How to set actionable push notifications in ios 10?

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications

Actually in my app design a push notification with yes/no button. give me any refrences

Comment: search for rich notifications

Comment: https://nrj.io/simple-interactive-notifications-in-ios-8/ it will work in ios10 too

Answer (score 0):

This can be implemented using Actionable push notifications.

Ref:
https://www.raywenderlich.com/156966/push-notifications-tutorial-getting-started